# Keep my MacBook playing audio when the lid is closed?

Tags: macos, power-management

I've got a MacBook 7,1 and I'd like to keep it running iTunes when  I close the lid. How can I do that?

Comment: if MacOS is at all similar to Windows then you would need to change the settings that determine what behavior the OS uses when the lid is closed to do nothing, rather than whatever behavior it uses now. hopefully someone with experience in MacOS can be more explicit.

Comment: @Xantec Nice try. There's no setting for that.

Comment: I just turn down the display light (lowest level = off) and keyboard lights whenever I want iTunes to continue playing. Collects a bit of dust, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InsomniaX folks mention [Sleepless](http://www.alxsoft.com/mac/sleepless.html), a commercial competitor (9.50 USD). At least it's obviously compatible with SL.

> This application is used to prevent the computer from going to sleep without changing system settings.
>
> ATTENTION! Using your Mac with closed lid can lead to serious system heat problems!
>
> ATTENTION **Snow Leopard** users! You need to use version 2.7 and up.

Comment: Looks like Sleepless would be the answer, but I'm not looking into that anymore. I just wanted that information as a one-time thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A software solution is [InsomniaX](http://semaja2.net/insomniaxinfo)

A hardware solution is [Apple Portables: How to use your computer in closed clamshell (display closed) mode with an external display](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3131?viewlocale=en_US) and also [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3131?viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: Has anyone used InsomniaX successfully on 10.6 SL? I'm a bit reluctant to install a kernel extension from 2006 (10.4 Tiger was the latest and greatest OS)...

Answer (score 0):

Your MacBook will normally always go to sleep when you close the lid, and that unfortunately will stop the music playing.

But there is a way to stop your Mac from going to sleep when you close the lid with a simple shell command.

Disable sleeping when lid is closed:

```
sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1
```

Re-enable sleeping when lid is closed:

```
sudo pmset -a disablesleep 0
```

from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/366131